# Razor pages: Redirecting to another page, second parameter is always null

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-6.0

I have a simple page with the following javascript callback function:

```
function completeCallback(response) {                            
   // redirect to Result page
   window.location.href = '@Url.Page("/Result", new {result = "def", orderId = "abc"})';
}
```

My aim is to redirect to another page passing two parameters, `result` and `orderId`.

This is how my `Result` page looks like:

```
public class ResultModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string orderId { get; set; }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string result { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var res = result;
    }
}
```

My problem is that while the first parameter is correctly set, the *second* parameter, `orderId` in this case, is **always** null. If I swap the parameters like this:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Page("/Result", new {orderId = "abc", result = "def"})';
```

then `orderId` is correctly set and `result` becomes `null`.

The url generated by `@Url.Page` command is as follows:

```
/Result?orderId=abc&amp;result=def
```

This is also what I've tried with same result:

```
public void OnGet(string orderId, string result)
{
   var res = result;
}
```

It's been a while since I last used .NET Core 3.1, but I'm almost certain I've used the same code before without any issues. Now, I'm using .NET 6.0. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: What does the `/Result` URL look like in the browser?

Comment: @RichardDeeming Please check the edit I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to `&` being escaped as `&amp;` by `@Url.Page`. To handle this I wrapped `@Url.Page` inside `@Html.Raw`:

```
window.location.href = '@Html.Raw(Url.Page("/Result", new {orderId = "abc", result = "def"}))';
```